# Irreducible polynomial of degree $8$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Would you please help me to prove this problem.

Let $G=\mathrm{Hol}(C_8)$. And let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $8$, $L$ a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})\cong G$.

> Show that there is a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$.
>   I am reviewing for my test and i find this good exercice [image]

Thanks.

Comment: What in the world is $\;"Hol(C_8)"\;$ ?

Comment: @ DonAntonio, the holomorph $Hol(\Gamma)$ of a group $\Gamma$ is the semidirect product $Hol(\Gamma)=\Gamma\ltimes_{\phi} Aut(\Gamma)$ where $\phi: Aut(\Gamma)\to  Aut(\Gamma)$ is the identity map.

Comment: Thanks, I know what the holomorph is. I just didn't recognize the notation...which, of course, makes sense.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: One question: isn't this trivial? I mean: it is always true that if we have a Galois extension of fields $\;L/k\;$ and $\;L\;$ is the splitting field of some irreducible polynomial $\;f(x)\in k[x]\;$ ,then $\;Gal(L/k)\cong G\le S_n\;$ , with $\;n=\deg f\;$ ... Am I missing something? In fact, with this condition we know $\;G\;$ *must be* a transitive subgroup of $\;S_n\;$ .

Comment: I think that you are right , can you please detail how to prove that general result? and that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$? down as an answer, I will be greathfull if you do so. Thanks in advance

Comment: I added an answer. Hopefully you can fill up details within it. If you have any doubts please do write back under the answer, in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement of the result

*$S_8$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $G=\mathrm{Hol}(C_8)$*

does not have anything to do with Galois theory. And, indeed, you can see that it is true without mentioning polynomials at all. Let $C \cong C_8$ be the subgroup of $S_8$ generated by the $8$-cycle $(12345678)$. The group of automorphisms of $C_8$ is the group of units modulo $8$ (also known as the Klein $4$-group). These are achieved via the conjugation action within $S_8$ by the subgroup $V$ generated by 
$$(24)(37)(68), \ (28)(37)(46), \ \text{and} \ (26)(84).$$ 
The subgroup generated by $C$ and $V$ is isomorphic to $G$ (it is enough to check that the conjugates of our $8$-cycle by the elements of $V$ produce precisely its first, third, fifth, and seventh powers).

It is also true that this occurrence of $G$ as a subgroup of $S_8$ is unique up to conjugacy: start with the simple observation that there is a unique up to conjugacy element of $S_8$ of order $8$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$. It contains an $8$-cycle, which we may assume is $(12345678)$. Since $H \cong G$, there must be some $v \in H$ with
$$v (12345678) v^{-1}=(12345678)^3=(14725836).$$ Since $C$ is self-centralizing, any such $v$ has the form $$v=(24)(37)(68) c$$ for some $c \in C$. It follows that $(24)(37)(68) \in H$, and similarly the other elements of order two written down above belong to $H$. This implies that $H$ is the group we wrote down before, by order considerations.

Comment: I don't see how you prove that any two subgroups of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$ are conjugate in $S_8$?  can you please detail that more? thanks

Comment: @siwar Maybe later, don’t have time at the moment! Why don’t you try with the hints I gave?

Comment: I will think more. Can you please write your answer when you have time. Since i am reviewing for a test tomorow and i feel realy stressed. Thanks in advance

Comment: @siwar Sure, there you go.

Comment: @Steven this answer the hall question b)?

Comment: @siwar Yes it does. And in case you haven’t read the comments to the other answer, it is my opinion that the answer given there is not what the exercise is asking for.

Comment: @ Stephen, so if i understand  well, to answer the question b) it is better to write your answer than the answer of  DonAntonio, right?

Comment: @siwar That is my opinion, yes.

Comment: thanks a lot! and have you an idea about the question c) i tried to solve it but i don't manage to do that

Comment: @siwar Yes. Part (c) is where Galois theory comes in for the first time. Consider the subgroup $G_1=\mathrm{fix}_G(\alpha)$. You know that $G$ is as described in my answer, which implies that we may assume the subgroup $G_1$ Is $V$ (after conjugating it). Moreover, we know precisely what the orbits of $G_1$ on the roots of $f$ are. Consequence: standard Galois theory implies that $f$ factors as the product of two linear polynomials (the fixed points of $V$), a quadratic (the orbit containing $3$ and $7$) and a fourth degree polynomial (the orbit of $2,4,6$ and $8$.

Comment: that is perfect! and how we can find the m is the part d)?

Comment: Dude! If you have digested the previous comment, you’re on your way. Go think about it yourself for a minute.

Comment: can you please detail more why ''Consequence: standard Galois theory implies that ......'' thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let us give it a try (haven't taught Galois Theory in the last years...:)) :

Suppose we have a field $\;k\;$ and an irreducible $\;f(x)\in k[x]\;$ with $\;\deg f=n\;$, say . We suppose everything is separable here, and let $\;L\;$ be the splitting field (the one and unique up to $\;k\,-$ isomorphism) of $\;f\;$ over $\;k\;$, so $\;L/k\;$ is a Galois extension.

Since $\;G:=Gal(L/k)\;$ acts transitivily over the roots of $\;f\;$ in $\;L\;$ (in fact, this is an iff condition: a polynomial in $\;k[x]\;$ with at least one root in $\;L\;$ is irreducible iff $\;G\;$ acts transitively over its roots. This makes sense since $\;L/k\;$ is normal and thus *an irredubile* polynomial having a root there automatically has all its roots in $\;L\;$) , we can embed $\;G\;$ into $\;S_n\;$ in the obvious way (observe all the roots of $\;f\;$ are distinct since we assume separability!) ...and that's all.

Of course, the above relies heavily on some basic facts from Galois Theory.

Comment: That is perfect!, and is it true that any two subgroups of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$ are conjugate in $S_8$? if so, do you know how to prove that?

Comment: @siwar I don't think that's necessarily true. If, for example, $\;G\;$ was a Sylow subgroup then yes, of course. And any two subgroups of $\;S_8\;$ isomorphic to $\;G\;$ are going to be isomorphic to each other...but I doubt that **has** to be an inner automorphism of $\;S_8\;$ . Now, if the isomorphism of those two subgroup of $\;S_8\;$ that are isomorphic with $\;G\;$ is by means of an automorphism of $\;S_8\;$ then the answer is **yes** since $\;S_n\;$ is complete for $\;6\neq n\in\Bbb N\;$ ...

Comment: My question is :  How to show that two subgroups of $S_8$  isomorphic to  $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ are conjugate in $S_8$?

Comment: @siwar I don't know, but: what does that have to do *at all* with your original question as written above?

Comment: @ DonAntonio, i think that the answer of Stephen is true do you think so?

Comment: @siwar Of course it is true...but it doesn't address what **you wrote in your question**, namely: that the given holomorph is in fact isomorphic with the Galois group of some polynomial. What Stephen is doing is taking the holomorph's definition as a permutation group.

Comment: i add the exercice that i am reviewing, perhaps we will need the hint to answer other questions and so the answer of  Stephen is accepted, no?

Comment: @siwar I think the question you just added is very clear: they want you to *focus* on polynomials, Galois extensions and Galois groups, not merely in the fact that Hol$\,(C_8)\;$ can be seen as a subgroup of $\;S_8\;$ .

Comment: and so what you wrote is more convenient, but i don't see how the answer the second part of the question b)

Comment: @siwar That's something you added just a few minutes ago! Besides this, it is customary to ask only one, or at most, two questions in the same post...

Comment: @ DonAntonio , i post the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641710/conjugation-in-s-8

Comment: @Stephen It is both true and fair and square. The first version of the OP's question (look into the edits) only asked about $\;Gal(L/\Bbb Q)\;$ beings isomorphic to a subgroup of $\;S_8\;$ . That's all...and the polynomial, its degree, splitting field, etc are there. Pointing out that Hol$\,(C_8)\;$ is a subgroup of $\;S_8\;$ without any reference to Galois Theory is nice, true and even interesting...but it misses the question **as it is** .

Comment: @Stephen But I did prove **what the OP asked** . His was **not** a question merely in group theory: it was a question within Galois Theory, and I think that what I did was **exactly** what was meanto to be done according to the **original question** asked...